# AddReference doesn't display on pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, clr, add-references-dialog

I want to use a dll from C# in my python script, using clr and `AddReference`.

After  importing clr, I can't use `AddReference` attribute [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw7x0.png). But when I do `print( dir(clr))`, it shows me the attribute `AddReference` [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnAr.png).

I tried to Install .NET on my notebook:

hier a screenshot after running my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljGlJ.png)

- add new folder
- `pip uninstall clr` then `pip install pythonnet`

Comment: If `dir` lists it, you can use it. Pop-up hints can't always show everything, because oftentimes attributes are unknown until runtime.

Comment: getting error after running my script  @aele1502

Comment: That's not enough information for me to say anything. You should share a traceback, at the very least